# React testing library - cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined while mocking named class component import

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I am getting error while testing a component with mocked child. So the component A which I want to test has a component B as child which further has component C as child. I am trying to mock the C component. Here is how C is in its source file:

```
// C.js

export class C extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    autoBind(this);
  }
 // ... code ...
}
```

in my A.test.js, I have following

```
jest.mock('<PATH_TO_C.JS>', () => ({
  C: jest.fn(() => '')
})
```

on running the test I am getting error pointing to my custom render: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined`

Answer (score 0):

You should return a mock JSX element as opposed to a jest function,

```js
jest.mock('<PATH_TO_C.JS>', () => ({
  C: () => <div>Sample Component Content</div>
})
```

Comment: Tried it, still get the same error.

Comment: I think we need to see all the moving parts involved to tell where the problem is. Few more things to check. Are you placing the `jest.mock` statement outside describe? Is the path to the component correct? Is it working if you comment out component C usage in B in actual component code?